# Optimizing google apps script for sales planning

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Follow up question to: [Planning dashboard for sales in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483445/planning-dashboard-for-sales-in-google-sheets/61517502#61517502)

I wrote a script in google apps script that solved the problem of assigning leads to channels based on overall sales target.

The script I wrote works but its hardcoded. I was hoping for some help to optimize it - can anyone help me with this?

Script:

```
function calculate() {

  // Get the planning sheet  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Planner')

  // Get contract target as the input
  var target = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue()

  // Clear the pin cards list
  sheet.getRange('D11:D15').clearContent()

  // Set the value of the first channel
  firstChannelValue(sheet, target)

  // Set the value of the second channel
  secondChannelValue(sheet, target)

  // Set the value of the third channel
  thirdChannelValue(sheet, target)

  // Set the value of the fourth channel
  fourthChannelValue(sheet, target)

  // Set the value of the fifth channel
  fifthChannelValue(sheet, target)

}

function firstChannelValue(sheet, target) {

  // Max number of pin cards
  var pcLimit = sheet.getRange('E11').getValue()

  // Conversion rate
  var convRate = sheet.getRange('F11').getValue()

  // Cell that needs to be filled
  var pinCard = sheet.getRange('D11')

  // Max possible value
  var maxValue = pcLimit*convRate

  // Set value of cell  
  if (maxValue <= target) {  
    pinCard.setValue(pcLimit)    
  }
  else {
    pinCard.setValue(target/convRate)
  }  
}


function secondChannelValue(sheet, target) {

  // Max number of pin cards
  var pcLimit = sheet.getRange('E12').getValue()

  // Conversion rate
  var convRate = sheet.getRange('F12').getValue()

  // Cell that needs to be filled
  var pinCard = sheet.getRange('D12')

  // Max possible value
  var maxValue = (pcLimit*convRate)

  // Value of first channel contracts
  var firstChannel = sheet.getRange('G11').getValue()

  // Revised target
  var revisedTarget = target - firstChannel

  // Set value of cell  
  if (maxValue <= revisedTarget) {  
    pinCard.setValue(pcLimit)    
  }
  else {
    pinCard.setValue(revisedTarget/convRate)
  }    
}


function thirdChannelValue(sheet, target) {

  // Max number of pin cards
  var pcLimit = sheet.getRange('E13').getValue()

  // Conversion rate
  var convRate = sheet.getRange('F13').getValue()

  // Cell that needs to be filled
  var pinCard = sheet.getRange('D13')

  // Max possible value
  var maxValue = (pcLimit*convRate)

  // Value of previous channel contracts
  var firstChannel = sheet.getRange('G11').getValue()
  var secondChannel = sheet.getRange('G12').getValue()

  // Revised target
  var revisedTarget = target - firstChannel - secondChannel

  // Set value of cell  
  if (maxValue <= revisedTarget) {  
    pinCard.setValue(pcLimit)    
  }
  else {
    pinCard.setValue(revisedTarget/convRate)
  }    
}


function fourthChannelValue(sheet, target) {

  // Max number of pin cards
  var pcLimit = sheet.getRange('E14').getValue()

  // Conversion rate
  var convRate = sheet.getRange('F14').getValue()

  // Cell that needs to be filled
  var pinCard = sheet.getRange('D14')

  // Max possible value
  var maxValue = (pcLimit*convRate)

  // Value of previous channel contracts
  var firstChannel = sheet.getRange('G11').getValue()
  var secondChannel = sheet.getRange('G12').getValue()
  var thirdChannel = sheet.getRange('G13').getValue()

  // Revised target
  var revisedTarget = target - firstChannel - secondChannel - thirdChannel

  // Set value of cell  
  if (maxValue <= revisedTarget) {  
    pinCard.setValue(pcLimit)    
  }
  else {
    pinCard.setValue(revisedTarget/convRate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the row as another parameter to a single function instead of five, like this:

```
function calculate() {

  // Get the planning sheet  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Planner')

  // Get contract target as the input
  var target = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue()

  // Clear the pin cards list
  sheet.getRange('D11:D15').clearContent();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var row = i + 11;
  channelValue(sheet, target, row);

}
}

function channelValue(sheet, target, row) {

  // Max number of pin cards
  var pcLimit = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue()

  // Conversion rate
  var convRate = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue()

  // Cell that needs to be filled
  var pinCard = sheet.getRange(row, 4)

  // Max possible value
  var maxValue = (pcLimit*convRate)

  // Value of previous channel contracts

  var revisedTarget = 0;

  for (var j = row; j > 11; j--){
    // Revised target
    revisedTarget += target - sheet.getRange(j, 9).getValue()
  }
  // Set value of cell  
  if (maxValue <= revisedTarget) {  
    pinCard.setValue(pcLimit)    
  }
  else {
    pinCard.setValue(revisedTarget/convRate)
  }    
}
```